# Where is the complete documentation of set-dispatch-macro-character?

Tags: common-lisp

I am trying to find the complete documentation of `set-dispatch-macro-character`. I have tried the [HyperSpec](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_set__1.htm), but it seems to be incomplete; the exact specification of the `new-function` argument is not mentioned. It only says that `new-function` is a "function designator" without stating how many arguments the function designator takes and what those arguments are.

Since the HyperSpec is incomplete, what are some canonical reference materials that Common Lisp programmers use to get the exact specifications of Common Lisp built-ins?

Comment: Okay, I realize my mistake now. Please be gentle. It is not easy for beginners to jump directly into the HyperSpec.

Comment: You'll also find examples and explanations in Common Lisp Recipes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of `set-dispatch-macro-character` contains the following cross-reference:

> For more information about how the new-function is invoked, see Section [2.1.4.4 (Macro Characters)](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_add.htm).

The details you ask for are in that section. In particular, it says:

> The reader macro function associated with the sub-character C2 is invoked with three arguments: the stream, the sub-character C2, and the infix parameter P.

Comment: Thank you. I should have been more careful in reading all those documents. I was intimidated by that wall of hyperlinked text.

Comment: Standards are not generally intended to be end user documentation, so they can be intimidating.

Comment: Is there no API documentation for Common Lisp that is separate from the standard?

Comment: There have been lots of books written.